# How to customize the input element generated by django.forms?

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm using django.forms to generate my login/signup page, part of code is as follows:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
<table>
<tr>
    {# username is directed to email field in our model #}
    <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="login" />
{% if next %}
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
{% else %}
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{% url 'home' %}" />
{% endif %}
</form>
```

As you can see, the `{{ form.username }}` and `{{ form.password }}` will automatically generate an `<input id="id_username" maxlength="254" name="username" type="text">` and an `<input id="id_password" name="password" type="password">` respectively. But I want to add some extra attributes to these `input` fields, like `placeholder`and `class`. Where can I customize these?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Either manually:

```
<input type="text" name="{{ form.field.html_name }}" placeholder="foo" value="{{ form.field.value }}" />
```

Or via the widget attrs argument
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    field = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placehoder': 'foo', 'title': 'baz'}))
```

Answer (score 6):

You may use [`django-widget-tweaks`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-widget-tweaks) which is a very nice library for tweaking django's widget. I've used it and it's quite simple.

From their site:

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}
<!-- change input type (e.g. to HTML5) -->

{% render_field form.search_query type="search" %}

<!-- add/change several attributes -->
{% render_field form.text rows="20" cols="20" title="Hello, world!" %}

<!-- append to an attribute -->
{% render_field form.title class+="css_class_1 css_class_2" %}

<!-- template variables can be used as attribute values -->
{% render_field form.text placeholder=form.text.label %}
```

Hope this helps!